# Modeling ruby subclasses in ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two classes:

```
class Comment > ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :tasks
end

class Work > ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :tasks
end
```

each also includes a common field called content: string (along with the standard fields for user_id, created_at, etc)

belonging to

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base 
    has_many :comments
    has_many :works
end
```

What I want to do now is add a parent class called Activity for Comment and Work so that I can pull all Comments and Works from their respective tables for a specified Task containing the common fields, and I'm not sure how to back fit this in Ruby and Rails.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called single table inheritance.

```
class Comment < Activity
   belongs_to :tasks
end

class Work < Activity
    belongs_to :tasks
end
```

You will not have a `Comments` table or a `Works` table. You will only have an `Activitys` table.  In the table, make a column called `type` that holds a string.  Rails considers this type column special and will know that you are referring to another model as opposed to just a string.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  What if each subclass also contains other class specific fields.  For example, work also contains a work_time field.  Also, could you give me some insight on how to write a migration for this.

Comment: You've just hit on the problem with subclasses. Inheritance and class methods. Which is the reason most people will probably warn you away from using STI as it tends to have a lot of unintended side effects.

Comment: Yeah, understood.  Basically I already have my tables for comments and work.  What I want to be able to do is get all comments and work entries for a specific task sorted by their created_at field.  Would there be a way to do this with my existing set up?